# Passar variáveis em todos os renders

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, view, render

Tenho uma aplicação usando NodeJS, Express (e mais algumas dependências). Reduzi a aplicação ao arquivo abaixo para explicar minha pergunta:

app.js:

```
// Dependências.
const express = require('express');

// Criar a instância do express.
let app = express();

// Middlewares.
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './public/views');
app.use('/assets', express.static('./public/assets'));

// Rotas.
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Título' });
});

app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  res.render('users', { title: 'Título' });
});

app.get('/groups', function (req, res) {
  res.render('groups', { title: 'Título' });
});

app.get('/calendar', function (req, res) {
  res.render('calendar', { title: 'Título' });
});

// Iniciar o servidor.
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Server listening at port ${port}.`);
});
```

Note que em todos os `app.get`, eu passei uma variável para a view. Esta variável é: `title`.

Há algum jeito de sempre passar uma variável para as views sem necessariamente colocá-las no segundo parâmetro da função `render()`?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Você pode definir variáveis locais utilizando o objeto [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#app.locals) ou [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#res.locals).

#### Diferenças entre eles.

- *app.locals - o valor das propriedades persiste ao longo da vida do aplicativo*. Para utilizar, basta:

  ```
  app.locals.titulo = 'Título do Meu Site';
  app.locals.email_contato = 'contato@meusite.com.br';
  ```
- *res.locals - as propriedades são válidas somente para a vida útil da solicitação*. Para utilizar, basta:

  ```
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
      res.locals.titulo = 'Título do Meu Site';
      res.locals.email_contato = 'contato@meusite.com.br';
      next();
  });
  ```

Ambos na *views*, por exemplo:

```
<% console.log(titulo); %>
<% console.log(email_contato); %>
```

#### Referências:

- [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#app.locals)
- [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#res.locals)

Comment: Muito obrigado!